# What's the idiomatic way to map producing 0 or 1 results per entry?

Tags: scala

What's the idiomatic way to call map over a collection producing 0 or 1 result per entry?

Suppose I have:

```
val data = Array("A", "x:y", "d:e")
```

What I'd like as a result is:

```
val target = Array(("x", "y"), ("d", "e"))
```

(drop anything without a colon, split on colon and return tuples)

So in theory I think I want to do something like:

```
val attempt1 = data.map( arg => {
    arg.split(":", 2) match {
      case Array(l,r) => (l, r)
      case _ => (None, None)
    }
  }).filter( _._1 != None )
```

What I'd like to do is avoid the need for the any-case and get rid of the `filter`.

I could do this by pre-filtering (but then I have to test the regex twice):

```
val attempt2 = data.filter( arg.contains(":") ).map( arg => {
      val Array(l,r) = arg.split(":", 2)
      (l,r)
    })
```

Last, I could use Some/None and flatMap...which does get rid of the need to `filter`, but is it what most scala programmers would expect?

```
val attempt3 = data.flatMap( arg => {
     arg.split(":", 2) match {
       case Array(l,r) => Some((l,r))
       case _ => None
     }
})
```

It seems to me like there'd be an idiomatic way to do this in Scala, is there?

Comment: You'll want `.collect` :) although due to the design of `PartialFunction`, it will still run your regex twice per element :/

Comment: I take that "twice per element" comment back. It looks like Scala's now a bit more clever about not calling `unapply` unnecessarily when building its "magic" partial functions from match blocks. I still hate the `PartialFunction` interface, but it looks like they jump through a bunch of hoops now to make it less stupid where possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With a `Regex` extractor and `collect` :-)

```
scala> val R = "(.+):(.+)".r
R: scala.util.matching.Regex = (.+):(.+)

scala> Array("A", "x:y", "d:e") collect {
     |   case R(a, b) => (a, b)
     | }
res0: Array[(String, String)] = Array((x,y), (d,e))
```

**Edit:**

If you want a map, you can do:

```
scala> val x: Map[String, String] = Array("A", "x:y", "d:e").collect { case R(a, b) => (a, b) }.toMap
x: Map[String,String] = Map(x -> y, d -> e)
```

If performance is a concern, you can use `collection.breakOut` as shown below to avoid creation of an intermediate array:

```
scala> val x: Map[String, String] = Array("A", "x:y", "d:e").collect { case R(a, b) => (a, b) } (collection.breakOut)
x: Map[String,String] = Map(x -> y, d -> e)
```

Comment: If I wanted a Map instead of tuples I suppose throwing a `.toMap` at the end is reasonable?

Comment: @MarkElliot, yes. Or if performance is the concern, you can use `collection.breakOut` to avoid creating intermediate array in that case. I will expand my answer.